# Do properties hold their value

Tags: c#, class, properties

If I create a new Class, and in this class I put a property like so:

```
public class CurrentDirectory
{
    private string cd;

    public string CurrentDirectory
    {
        get
        {
            return cd;
        }
        set
        {
            cd = value;
        }
    }
```

I then, at one point in my program, create a new instance of this class like so:

```
CurrentDirectory myCurrentDirectory = New CurrentDirectory();
```

I then set a value to CurrentDirectory like so:

```
myCurrentDirectory.CurrentDirectory = @"C:\MyFiles\Here";
```

Then, at another point in my program I create another instance of CurrentDirectory and 'get' the value of CurrentDirectory like so:

```
CurrentDirectory myCurrentDirectory1 = new CurrentDirectory();
string putFilesHere = myCurrentDirectory1.CurrentDirectory;
```

Will this return the value I set earlier or do I need to 'get' and 'set' my value within the same instance?

Thanks

Comment: This smells of homework.

Comment: It's not homework, I'm just an idiot!

Comment: Hey, you're not an idiot: probably you're just a newbie, like everyone of us was years ago :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, this does not hold values in this way, no more than setting one user's name to "Heisenburg" affects my name of "Anthony Pegram". Each instance of the class is a different object, and instance properties and members of one instance do not carry over to other instances.

```
User user = new User(); // this is my object!
user.Name = "Anthony Pegram"; // this is my name! 

User otherUser = new User(); // this is your object!
otherUser.Name = "Heisenburg"; // this is your name! 

// my object is not your object
```

If you need to share properties to where some other place sees the same value you set elsewhere, you need to either share the *instance*, or make the data itself *shared* via the `static` keyword on the property.

```
class Foo
{
    public static string Bar { get; set; }
}
```

If using statics, the state becomes *global*, and is not tied to a particular *instance.* It, in fact, does not need an instance. You would simply access it via the class name directly, not via an object of that class.

```
Foo.Bar = "Blah"; // no instance necessary
string data = Foo.Bar;
```

Comment: Thanks very much for this, all of the other answers were really helpful also =)

Answer (score 4):

You need to get and set within the same variable instance.
If you need a *global* class, you could create a [singleton](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2155688/what-is-a-singleton-in-c) class (see [this example](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff650316.aspx))

Answer (score 3):

No that won't return the value you set earlier since that property is instance-specific.
IF you want a property being shared by all instances then you need to make it [`static`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/79b3xss3%28v=VS.100%29.aspx).

Answer (score 3):

Two different instances are will have two different property values.  When you create a new instance, you're creating a whole new object with it's own `CurrentDirectory` property.

If you're trying to create a copy of the object you already have for some reason, look into Cloning.

Answer (score 2):

No.

This is a new object and would have the default values for the new object.  In this case it would be nothing.

Answer (score 1):

Your new instance, is, as the word indicates, a **new instance** therefore, the value you set earlier will hold for the other instance (myCurrentDirectory), `myCurrentDirectory1` is an object of the same type with its own values. You need to set and get the values on the same instance on this case.

If you set `myCurrentDirectory1=myCurrentDirectory;` then both will hold the same values since they are really pointers to the same place in memory.