# Thread safety on readonly static field initialisation

Tags: c#, multithreading, thread-safety

If one creates a readonly static member like this:

```
public sealed class MyClass
{
    public readonly static MyClass Instance = new MyClass();
}
```

We know that the static constructor will initialise the MyClass.Instance field if some thread accesses MyClass the fist time. But, will a single instance (in this case MyClass) be created if multiple threads all accesses MyClass at the same time (i.e. is the initialisation of the static field thread-safe)?

Comment: You'll have only one instance, but it won't be thread-safe. You must implement your access control to it (`Mutex` or whatever).

Comment: I know the instance members of the class still need to be thread-safe, my question is is the initialisation of the readonly static fields thread-safe (i.e. will the static constructor only ever be called by one thread?)

Comment: It will be called just once by the runtime. It's like you had a *singleton* to the whole application.

Comment: There will be an instance of `MyClass` per `AppDomain`.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

.NET CLR ensures that static initialization is always thread-safe. No matter how many threads are accessing it and what order, it will always be initialized once.

Your code seems to show signs of the beginnings of a Singleton pattern.
Basically if you want to run custom code before you initialize the class, then you need to ensure thread-safety on your own.
[This is an example](http://csharpindepth.com/Articles/General/Singleton.aspx) where you would need to make your custom code thread safe. But the static initialization part is always thread safe.

Comment: *".NET CLR ensures that static initialisation is always thread-safe."* this is true **unless** someone is trying to do **really weird** things. Like this code will result in deadlock: `using System.Threading;
class Foo
{
    static void Main() { }

    static Foo()
    {
        Thread thread = new Thread(arg => { });
        thread.Start();
        thread.Join();
    }
}`

Comment: Another exception would be marking a static member as ThreadStatic.

Answer (score 10):

The class initialization is guaranteed by the specification of the C# language to be thread safe, so only one instance of `MyClass` will be created. You would have to ensure thread safety from that point onwards yourself. Here's an MSDN reference:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa645612.aspx

Comment: I'm still trying to find it... Got it, added to answer.

Comment: link no longer valid @davidm