# Singleton shortened implementation

Tags: c#

I always see singletons implemented like this:

```
public class Singleton
{
    static Singleton instance;
    static object obj = new object();

    public static Singleton Instance
    {
        get
        {
            lock (obj)
            {
                if (instance == null)
                {
                    instance = new Singleton();
                }
                return instance;
            }
        }
    }

    protected Singleton() { }
}
```

Is there's something wrong with implementing it like this:

```
public class Singleton
{
    static readonly Singleton instance = new Singleton();
    public static Singleton Instance
    {
        get { return instance; }
    }

    protected Singleton() { }
}
```

? It gets lazy initialized on the very same moment as in the first implementation so I wonder why this isn't a popular solution?
It should be also faster because there's no need for a condition, locking and the field is marked as readonly which will let the compiler to do some optimisations

Let's not talk about the singleton (anti)pattern itself, please

Comment: You might be interested in reading Jon Skeet's [Implementing the Singleton Pattern in C#](http://csharpindepth.com/Articles/General/Singleton.aspx), scroll down to "Fourth version - not quite as lazy, but thread-safe without using locks"

Comment: Its a matter of taste. There's a third pattern with `Lazy<T>`, as well. Note that your first example should also have a check of nullity *before* entering the lock.

Comment: There's nothing wrong with implementing it like that (other than you should declare the backing field as `readonly`). But note that it's not as lazy as the first version since the object is created when a static method in the class is called, rather than when the property is accessed.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The CLR [will initialize the field upon the first use](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa645758%28v=vs.71%29.aspx) of that (or any other static) field. It [promises to do so in a thread-safe manner](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12159698/thread-safety-on-readonly-static-field-initialisation).

The difference between your code is that the first bit of code supports thread-safe lazy initialization where the second doesn't. This means that when your code never accesses `Singleton.Instance` of the first code, no `new Singleton()` will ever be created. For the second class it will, as soon as you access `Instance` *or (directly or indirect) any other static member* of that class. Worse even - it [may be initialized before that](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/610818/what-does-beforefieldinit-flag-do) because you lack a static constructor.

Favoring shorter and more readable code, since .NET 4 you can use `Lazy<T>` to significantly shorten the first code block:

```
public class Singleton
{
    static readonly Lazy<Singleton> instance = 
        new Lazy<Singleton>(() => new Singleton());

    public static Singleton Instance
    {
        get { return instance.Value; }
    }

    static Singleton() { }
    private Singleton() { }
}
```

As `Lazy<T>` also [promises thread-safety](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd997286%28v=vs.110%29.aspx). This will ensure `new Singleton()` is only called once, and only when `Singleton.Instance` is actually used.

Comment: Worth noting that making the constructor `protected` will allow the class to be inherited and thus making it not a singleton.

Comment: @Sriram sure, it may as well be `private`. :)