# Is the X509Certificate2 class thread-safe?

Tags: c#, thread-safety

Tell me the [X509Certificate2](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.security.cryptography.x509certificates.x509certificate2?view=net-5.0) class is thread-safe? Conditionally, I can use it in this way:

```cs
public class MyClass 
{
    // example
    private static readonly X509Certificate2 staticCertInstance = 
        new X509Certificate2("cert.pfx");

    // the method can be called from different threads
    public void Execute() 
    {
        // use staticCertInstance 
    }
}
```

To avoid creating an instance every time, thereby reducing the load on the GC ?

Comment: You have a constant that is read only so once it is created it is thread safe.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Thread safety on readonly static field initialisation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12159698/thread-safety-on-readonly-static-field-initialisation)

Comment: None of its members are marked in the documentation as being thread-safe, so it may not be. If you want to reduce GC load, you could try creating an [ObjectPool](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.extensions.objectpool.objectpool-1?view=dotnet-plat-ext-5.0) of them?

Answer (score 1):

This object is not guaranteed to be thread safe since it has a "handle" method being itself a wrapper and using lower level functions.

If you are using .NET 4.6+ you should wrap the object inside a using statement to dispose it correctly or you can find problems copying to disk small certificates into several locations.

So use "lock" keyword if you are unsure and "using" statement.