# Can a singleton initialize thread-safely just use public static field rather a Lazy<T> or other Singleton solution?

Tags: c#, thread-safety, singleton

I want to create a `ConcurrentDictionary` to store some data in my project, and want to keep it during all my app's lifetime,so it can be access by different thread to get the cached data.

I must **make it's initialization thread-safe**, I don’t want it to be created twice when some thread access it at the same time.

I know that the static field be initialized when it be accessed first time.So I define the `ConcurrentDictionary` like this:

```cs
public class CacheData
{
    public readonly static ConcurrentDictionary<string, string> ConcurrentDic = new ConcurrentDictionary<string, string>();
}
```

As far as i know, it's a singleton, and it's thread-safe, so what confuses me most now is **I cannot find any reason to use any other solution to create a singleton** such as a `Lazy<ConcurrentDictionary<string, string>>` like:

```cs
public class CacheData
{
    private static Lazy<ConcurrentDictionary<string, string>> _concurrentDic = new Lazy<ConcurrentDictionary<string, string>>(() =>
    {
        return new ConcurrentDictionary<string, string>();
    });

    public static ConcurrentDictionary<string, string> ConcurrentDic
    {
        get
        {
            return _concurrentDic.Value;
        }
    }
}
```

**If `Lazy<T>` can be completely replaced by static field here, when will `Lazy<T>` be used?**

Looking forward to your answer

Comment: Your lazy dictionary is initialized once the **property** is used the first time, whereas the `static readonly` field is inisitialized when the **class** is used the very first time. So those two aren´t equivalent. Also see this post for thread-safety on static members: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12159698/thread-safety-on-readonly-static-field-initialisation

Comment: @HimBromBeere the static readonly field is inisitialized when **I first use the dictionary**, and I wrote a test program[Sample of Static Field](https://gist.github.com/GadHao/d57da32fb325a9ace74123698211201c)

Comment: For a lightweight object like a dictionary, then using a static variable is fine. But what if you have an object which takes 20 seconds to create, but you want to ensure you create only _one_ of them? Show us how you would do that _without_ `Lazy` or `LazyWithNoExceptionCaching` (https://stackoverflow.com/a/42567351/34092). **That** is why `Lazy` is useful - not because you need it everywhere, but because when you need it **you need it**.

Comment: `the static readonly field is inisitialized when I first use the dictionary,` That is an overly simplistic explanation. With your code _right now_ that might be true. It isn't _always_ true for all code and all runtimes. Your sample is simple, and so it acts simply. https://dotnetfiddle.net/l7lB1Y

Comment: @mjwills It just output once `The Dictionary has been initialized now` in this sample code [multithread inisitialize a static field](https://gist.github.com/GadHao/3b784d0d895849ec76f6115c3e8090a9)

Comment: @HaoGuo Ask yourself how `Bob has been called` was written to the console in my link without me using the variable. My link _disproves_ your hypothesis. You can clearly have a static field populated _without accessing it_. Also see https://dotnetfiddle.net/HhC6Gt . Now if you run my most recent dotnetfiddle on .NET 5, then yes the order is changed. But that is my point - you are relying on something that cannot be relied on. It _might_ act the way you say it does. it _might not_.

Comment: just imagine you´d had a second static member. If you´d use your dictionary the first time, that second member would **also** be initialized, whereas `Lazy` would only initialize the member you´re calling.

Comment: @mjwills I'm viewing the link page, thank you

Comment: @mjwills yes, when I run your code or my code in my `.NET Core 3.1` or `.NET 5 ` environment, it behave like I said, but when I run it in `.NET Framework`(In addition, I use 4.7.2) or in your link's code playground, it's not like this at all. I think now I am very clear about the difference between them, **you are relying on something that cannot be relied on.** fantastic answer!!! thank you!!!

Comment: @mjwills hi mjwills, would you like to summarize your comments into one answer? I think this is what i want, if you have no time to do that, maybe I will do it later

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Fundamentally, you are seeing behaviour that isn't guaranteed. Because it isn't guaranteed, you can't *rely* on it. Take the below code as an example. What output will it generate? The answer is **it depends**.

> 17.4.5.1: "If a static constructor (§17.11) exists in the class, execution of the static field initializers occurs immediately prior to
> executing that static constructor. Otherwise, the static field
> initializers are executed at an implementation-dependent time prior to
> the first use of a static field of that class."

*implementation-dependent* means multiple orders are valid, as long as the rules are kept.

It might generate:

```
The Dictionary has been initialized now
Start Running...
Start Running...
```

Or it might generate:

```
Start Running...
Start Running...
The Dictionary has been initialized now
```

You can validate it yourself at https://dotnetfiddle.net/d5Tuev (switch runtimes on the left side).

Now, in your testing you have experienced *one* of those behaviours. But that behaviour isn't guaranteed, and thus you shouldn't *rely* on it.

```
using System.Collections.Concurrent;
using System.Threading;

namespace Samples.Console
{
    public class Program
    {
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Thread thread1 = new Thread(() => StaticField.StaticFieldTest());
            Thread thread2 = new Thread(() => StaticField.StaticFieldTest());

            thread1.Start();
            thread2.Start();

            Thread.Sleep(1000);
        }

        public class StaticField
        {
            public static readonly ConcurrentDictionary<string, string> _dic = InitDictionary();

            public static void StaticFieldTest()
            {
                System.Console.WriteLine("Start Running...");

                _dic.TryAdd(string.Empty, string.Empty);
                _dic.TryAdd(string.Empty, string.Empty);
                _dic.TryAdd(string.Empty, string.Empty);
            }

            public static ConcurrentDictionary<string, string> InitDictionary()
            {
                System.Console.WriteLine("The Dictionary has been initialized now");
                Thread.Sleep(500);
                return new ConcurrentDictionary<string, string>();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

In addition - `Lazy` or [`LazyWithNoExceptionCaching`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42567351/34092) are quite useful in some contexts - e.g. if you have an object which takes 20 seconds to create, but you want to ensure you create only one of them.

Answer (score 2):

First off you´re not really using a singleton here. A singleton is just the one and only instance of a specific class. A `static` field in itself has no instance at all. There might be dozens of `ConcurrentDictionary` within your code and also a dozens instances of your class.

`static` just means: all instances - regardless on how many of those exist - share the same member, in your case the dictionary.

Apart from this your two appraoches aren´t equivalent, even though in your specific example they seem similar. The most important difference between a `static readonly` field and a `static Lazy` field, is that the former is initialized the very first time your **class** is used, whereas the latter is initialized when that **member** is used the very first time. Chances are the lazy member isn´t called in your entire code, so it wont be initialized at all.

Two make this more clear see this example:

```
public class CacheData
{
    private static readonly int myint = 3;
    private static Lazy<ConcurrentDictionary<string, string>> _concurrentDic = new Lazy<ConcurrentDictionary<string, string>>(() =>
    {
        return new ConcurrentDictionary<string, string>();
    });

    public static ConcurrentDictionary<string, string> ConcurrentDic
    {
        get
        {
            return _concurrentDic.Value;
        }
    }
}
```

Now you have two completely independ members here. While `myint` is initialized when your class is used, the dictionary stays un-initialized. Only when you try to access that dictionary it will be initialized:

```
class MyClass
{
    void DoSomething()
    {
        // this will initialize myint if not already done
        CacheData.DoSomething(); 
        // however the dictionary is not initialized, only if you try to access it
        console.WriteLine(CacheData.ConcurrentDic["Hello"]);
        // now the dictionary is also initialized
    }
}
```

To keep long stories short: `Lazy` is ment to defer (heavy) initialization as far as possible until needed, whereas a `static readonly` field will be initialized on class-initialization.

Comment: `is that the former is initialized the very first time your class is used,` I think it is slightly more subtle than that (hence how different runtimes can initialise it at different times).

Comment: Yes, I understand how `Lazy<T>` works. I think I have got the answer I want because of the difference in the performance of static fields initialization at different runtimes. like @mjwills said: **relying on something that cannot be relied on.**