# Singleton for global data

Tags: c#

I would like to ask how can I make below structured data globally available to all classes:

```
class clsData1
{
   int Num1;
   int Num2;
   string Str1;
}

class clsData2
{ 
   int Num3;
   int Num4;
   string Str2;
}

class Main
{
   clsData1 clsData1A;
   clsData2 clsData2A;
}
```

I guess solution is with singleton, but example would be helpful.

Aditionally I would like that this data structure works as global over all classes.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is a singleton in C#?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2155688/what-is-a-singleton-in-c)

Comment: by making the classes public for instance?

Comment: Duplicate was one of the first links for "c# singleton", do your own research first

Comment: No a Singleton only *guarantees* that there is one instance, whether it is available everywhere, is up to the programmer.

Answer (score 0):

As @Willem Van Onsem mentions in comments a SingleTon has nothing to do with wheather a class is accessable within the whole solution or not. However it only guarantees that for the class only one single instance can be created. So the following code usually doesn´t work for a singleton-class:

```
var myInstance = new MySingleton();
```

This can be achieved by defining a private constructor for `MySingleton`-class. Thus the constructor cannot be called from outside the class.

What you want to do is making your classes `public` which will allow you to access it anywhere. You may see [access-modifiers](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wxh6fsc7.aspx) for more information on `public`.

Comment: I would like to have only one instance of this data structure avaiable in whole app in all classes, like global variables.

Answer (score 0):

maybe I was not clear enough.

I would like that this data struct is working as global variable, avaiable in all classes, fo