# C# Check in outlook webcal is already added or not

Tags: c#, windows, outlook, webcal

hi I am trying to add webcal programmatically into the outlook

```
Outlook.Application ouApplication = new Outlook.Application();
Outlook.Folder newFolder = ouApplication.GetNamespace("MAPI").OpenSharedFolder("webcalURL") as Outlook.Folder;
```

but how can I check where the same webcal is already added...

```
if(!AlreadyAdded())
{
    Outlook.Application ouApplication = new Outlook.Application();
    Outlook.Folder newFolder = ouApplication.GetNamespace("MAPI").OpenSharedFolder("webcalURL") as Outlook.Folder;
}

bool AlreadyAdded()
{
     //Check webcal is already added or not
}
```

Comment: These two part of code is in same page ?

Comment: yes on same page... i want to webcam URL into the outlook but how can i check is already added or not... because is i added multiple time then in the outlook it shows multiple calendar...

Answer (score 0):

One method is to use a `private` object in your `class`:

```
private Outlook.Application ouApplication;
if(!AlreadyAdded())
{
   ouApplication = new Outlook.Application();
   Outlook.Folder newFolder = ouApplication.GetNamespace("MAPI").OpenSharedFolder("webcalURL") as Outlook.Folder;
}

bool AlreadyAdded()
{
   return ouApplication!=null;
}
```

Another method is to use a `singleton` class.

View reference [here.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2155688/what-is-a-singleton-in-c)

Comment: hmm no we cannot do this because...if after adder I removed the calendar from outlook and check it again its shows already added... so I need some way to get value from Outlook.. understand ?

Comment: When you delete calendar from outlook set `AlreadyAdded=false` and will work.

Comment: if i delete from Outlook not programmatically?