# How to call a Class = new Class(); declare one time?

Tags: c#, winforms, class, methods

In windows Form App I get call

```
  private Class1 c1;
  private void Print()
  {
            c1 = new Class1();
  }
```

but in next one i don't want to declare new Class because it make a wrong value for my program and get error.
      it's like

```
  private void Print2()
  {
            c1 ; //**( I don't want to declare new one )**
  }
```

**edit 2**
      i'd like to do like you said but argument in my code is like

```
    public CandleCollection GetCandleCollection()
    {
        CandleCollection collection = null;
        try
        {
            collection = SymbolList[cbxSymbol.Text];
        }
        catch (Exception) { }
        return collection;
    }       
    private Class1 c1 = new Class1(<collection>);  **it's need to call collection**
    private void Print()
    {
            c1 = new Class1();
    }
    private void Print2()
    {
            c1 ; //**( I don't want to declare new one )**
    }
```

**edit 3**
       This is my original code to call c1

```
    private void Print()
    {
        CandleCollection collection = GetCandleCollection();
        Class1 c1 = new Class1(collection);
    }
```

Comment: `private Class1 c1 = new Class1();`?

Comment: What is the funtionality that you want to achieve? I don't quite get it...

Comment: What's your problem exactly?

Comment: do want it to be singleton then make it a prop and check if the private variable assigned to property has been initiated if not then only initiate it. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2155688/what-is-a-singleton-in-c

Comment: Presuming that Print() and Print2() are in the same class, you need to read about properties in C#.

Comment: Use different Constructors then?

Comment: You're confusing declaration and definition. `c1` is declared as a field in the class, and initialised in `Print`. It will still exist in `Print2`, no need to initialise it again.

Comment: in my example. yes it can . but in my code it's like private Class1 c1 = new Class1( something inside );

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Move your `CandleCollection` variable out of the `public` method so you can also use it out of this method.

Then, you can instantiate the `Class1` variable only once:

```
private CandleCollection collection = null;

public CandleCollection GetCandleCollection()
{
    try
    {
        collection = SymbolList[cbxSymbol.Text];
    }
    return collection;
}       
private Class1 c1 = new Class1(collection);
private void Print()
{
        c1;
}
private void Print2()
{
        c1;
}
```

Comment: I updated post now. I want to do like you said but i have a problem with arguments

Comment: It's said "A field initializer cannot reference the non-static field, method, or property"

Comment: this means that you class is static. declare the variable also as static.

Comment: Pobably becase you have an unhandled exception. Add a `catch` to your `try` and see what the exception is.

Comment: It's working now but a c1 value is null . I think value is doesn't add in c1 ?

Comment: updated edit 3 , in this code c1 it have a value ( 10,...etc ) but if i change to this c1 value is turn to ( all value is 0 )

Comment: should i use singleton ?