# Instances of scoped services between subsequent requests

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

After learning about scoped/singleton/transient services [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38139500/881712), I'm trying to understand why this code doesn't work. It's written in ASP.NET Core 2.

startup.cs

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    // ... other services
    services.AddScoped<LiveData, LiveData>();
    services.AddScoped<Utils, Utils>();
}
```

livedata.cs

```
public class LiveData 
{
    public LiveData() {
        Plcs = new List<Plc>();
    }

    public List<Plc> Plcs { get; set; }
}

public class Plc
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public DateTime Datetime { get; set; }
    public string OperatorName { get; set; }
}
```

utils.cs

```
public class Utils
{
    private readonly LiveData _liveData;

    public Utils(LiveData liveData)
    {
        _liveData = liveData;
        // ... fill in _liveData.Plcs
    }

    public void SetOperatorName(string name, string operatorName)
    {
        Plc plc = _liveData.Plcs.SingleOrDefault(x => x.Name == name);
        plc.OperatorName = operatorName;
    }
}
```

testpage.chstml.cs

```
public class MachineDetailsModel : PageModel
{
    private readonly LiveData _liveData;
    private readonly Utils _utils;

    public MachineDetailsModel(LiveData liveData, Utils utils)
    {
        _liveData = liveData;
        _utils = utils;
    }

    public Plc Plc { get; set; }

    public async Task<IActionResult> OnGetAsync(string id)
    {
        Plc = _liveData.Plcs.SingleOrDefault(x => x.Name == id);
        return Page();
    }

    public IActionResult OnPostSetOperatorName(string name)
    {
        var operatorName = "foo";
        _utils.SetOperatorName(name, operatorName);
        Plc = _liveData.Plcs.SingleOrDefault(x => x.Name == name);
        return RedirectToPage();
    }
}
```

When the post handler is called, it correctly updates the `OperatorName` fields. Before returning I checked the `Plc` variable and it contains the new value "foo".
But when the page reloads (due to the post) and the `Plc` variable is set again (note the two lines are the same) the `OperatorName` is lost (null, as default).

As far as I understand the scoped services maintain the same instance for all requests in the same session (i.e. until I close the browser).
Did I understand it wrong?

Comment: `Did I understand it wrong?` Yes. The scope is the web request, not the 'session'.

Comment: Ok. I definitely need a singleton one here...

Comment: Well then you need to register it as singleton rather than scoped. Note that singleton means 'one object shared by all web requests', not 'one object per session'.

Comment: Does a singleton service "survive" on different "sessions"? I mean, when I close and reopen the browser, I will retrieve the same instance?

Comment: Yes. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2155688/what-is-a-singleton-in-c

Comment: Only one instance of a singleton service is ever created *per server instance*. Remember if you run in a web farm, there will be multiple instances on the different servers. You *may* need a database here :)

Comment: Correct @juunas - a singleton is per process.

Comment: You shouldn't just jump to "well, I'll just use singleton-scope instead". Anything in singleton scope needs to be 100% thread-safe. If you're doing stuff like manipulating lists, newing up instances of things, etc. you're most likely going to run into issues in a multithreaded environment like a web server. In other words, if you need to persist data between requests, use an actual persistent store, like a database. Singletons are rarely the right approach.