# Load form before Selenium Chromedriver

Tags: c#, selenium-chromedriver

So the way I have my code set up loads the ChromeDriver before displaying the form. I need the driver to be global though so I am not sure how to handle this. Current code:

```
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        DiscordSocketClient Client;
        IWebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
        string homeURL;
        string[,] betData = new string[15, 50];    
        int totalRows = 0;

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            cbDiscordChannel.SelectedIndex = 1;
            ConnectToDiscord();     
        }
```

Comment: What do you mean by 'global'? Static? You can put the assignment of `driver` inside `Form1_Load` then it starts after displaying the form.

Comment: If I move driver to Form1_Load I can no long use/access it in other methods

Comment: You should look into the [singleton pattern](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2155688/what-is-a-singleton-in-c)