# Thread safe singleton property in one line

Tags: c#, .net, conditional-operator, null-coalescing-operator

How can I write the following code in one line?

```
   private static LockSDP instance;
        private static readonly object _lock = new();
        public static LockSDP GetInstance
        {
            get
            {
                if (instance is null) lock (_lock) instance ??= new();
                return instance;
            }
        }
```

[image: error]

Comment: With [`Lazy<T>`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.lazy-1?view=net-7.0) :)

Comment: I know it makes more sense to use Lazy<T>. I was stubborn to write a single line but failed :') Thanks..

Comment: The round wheel version of your invention - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2155688/what-is-a-singleton-in-c (in particular https://csharpindepth.com/Articles/Singleton by *the* Jon Skeet)

Comment: (Updated title to match the task rather than attempted solution, but could not add proper code-golf tag as it is banned for obvious reason... Feel free to improve title more if you feel my edit did not exactly match your goal)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

not everything can *be* one line; however, this can perhaps be easier; you *could* use `Lazy<T>`, but for a simple `static` here where you're mostly after deferred instantiation, I would probably lean on static field behaviour and a nested class:

```
public static LockSDP GetInstance => LockProxy.Instance;
private static class LockProxy { public static readonly LockSDP Instance = new(); }
```

Answer (score 2):

I'd probably prefer [Marc's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75014995/982149) but just so it's there:

```
private static readonly Lazy<LockSDP> _lazyInstance = 
    new Lazy<LockSDP>(() => new LockSDP()); // Default is Threadsafe access.

public static LockSDP Instance => _lazyInstance.Value;
```

And yes: I do realize it is still 2 lines :/

For reference: [`Lazy<T>`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.lazy-1?view=net-7.0)

Comment: the default thread-safety mode (if `true` not specified) is `LazyThreadSafetyMode.ExecutionAndPublication`, which is what `true` produces, so... you can probably skip that ([source](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.lazy-1.-ctor)); nit: `_lazyInstance` should be `readonly`