# An obvious singleton implementation for .NET?

Tags: c#, .net, singleton

I was thinking about the classic issue of lazy singleton initialization - the whole matter of the inefficiency of:

```
if (instance == null)
{
    instance = new Foo();
}
return instance;
```

Anyone who knows what a Singleton is is familiar with the issue(you only need the if once). It's trivial but irritating.

So, I thought of an alternate solution, at least for .NET(although it should work anywhere
that has some equivalent to function pointers:

```
public class Foo
{
    private delegate Foo FooReturner();

    private static Foo innerFoo;

    private static FooReturner fooReturnHandler = new FooReturner(InitialFooReturner);

    public static Foo Instance
    {
        get
        {
            return fooReturnHandler();
        }
    }
    private static Foo InitialFooReturner()
    {
        innerFoo = new Foo();
        fooReturnHandler = new FooReturner(NewFooReturner); 
        return innerFoo;
    }

    private static Foo NewFooReturner()
    {
        return innerFoo;
    }

}
```

In short - the Instance returns a delegate method. The delegate is initially set to a method
that initializes your instance, then changes the delegate to point at a simple Return method.

Now, I like to think I'm not terrible at my job, but I have no pretensions about being awesome. I have not seen an example of this code anywhere.

Ergo, I come to the conclusion that I am missing something. Something major. Either that the whole problem is too trivial to bother thinking that much about or this does something horrible that will destroy the universe. Or I fail at searching and therefore haven't seen
the hundreds of developers using this method. Something, anyway.

I was hoping the good folks here at Stack Overflow could clue me in as to what(leaving aside the controversy on whether one should use a Singleton at all).

EDIT for clarification:

This is not performance code(although if the design actively degrades performance beyond the traditional model, that would be interesting to know).

It was written purely as proof-of-concept, and I am further aware that it is not thread-safe as it properly should be. Is there any reason why it could NOT be made thread-safe by it's very nature?

Comment: "inefficiency" - I'd worry more that it isn't actually thread-safe ;-p

Comment: Re the edit... but it adds complexity, and doesn't address any issue... why would you choose this over just a null check? If you want to fix the thread safety, read Jon's page...

Comment: +1 "Universe destruction" hypothesis. :P Apart from that, good question, and faved for the record.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

[This is the canonical, thread safe, lazy Singleton pattern in C#](http://csharpindepth.com/Articles/General/Singleton.aspx):

```
public sealed class Singleton
{
    Singleton(){}
    public static Singleton Instance
    {
        get
        {
            return Nested.instance;
        }
    }        
    class Nested
    {
        // Explicit static constructor to tell C# compiler
        // not to mark type as beforefieldinit
        static Nested() {}    
        internal static readonly Singleton instance = new Singleton();
    }
}
```

Comment: And for Java programmers, the equivalent is called the "Lazy Initialization Holder Class" idiom, described in Item 71 of Effective Java 2nd ed. :-)

Comment: That my be lazy to the MySingleton type, but it isn't necessarily granular to the .Instance property

Comment: See Jon's article referenced in Marc's answer; the "canonical" pattern may not be as lazy as we would like it to be.

Comment: We had linked the same article, but my short simplification was ill-advised. Ultimately, I have edited to duplicate Marc's answer. He should be given the accepted answer.

Comment: Nah - I'll delete mine; you can have it ;-p

Comment: @Marc Gravell: you didn't have to do that. Unless you were wanting a certain badge... :)

Comment: Sorry for the previous french... this code marks Singleton with  beforefieldinit AND Nested with beforefieldinit. Is marking Singleton with beforefieldinit really needed?

Answer (score 10):

To prevent from having to copy the singleton code, you could make the type generic, as such:

```
public abstract class Singleton<T>
    where T: class, new()
{
    public static T Instance
    {
        get { return Nested.instance; }
    }

    private class Nested
    {
        // Explicit static constructor to tell C# compiler
        // not to mark type as beforefieldinit
        static Nested() { }

        internal static readonly T instance = new T();
    }
}

public sealed class MyType : Singleton<MyType>
{
}

class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {
        // two usage pattterns are possible:
        Console.WriteLine(
            ReferenceEquals(
                Singleton<MyType>.Instance, 
                MyType.Instance
            )
        );
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
```

Comment: This abstract generic solution has a flaw. It relies on derived type publicly exposing a constructor, which in turn would allow anybody to use it. Typically ctor() has to be made private in order to force client's usage of MyType.Instance property. Imho copy-pasting implementation is a small price to pay in this case.

Comment: I wouldn't call it a flaw, it is a design choice.

Answer (score 4):

Have you measured the performance?

Do you believe that an additional function call is cheaper than an if?

I agree with the others that using the static ctor works well for this initialization.  This will also get rid of the inherent race condition that the you have since .net guarentees that static constructors will only be called once.

Answer (score 1):

> the whole matter of the inefficiency of:...

What inefficiency?

Those instructions will result into an extremely fast fragments of assembly code. I am completely sure that there is nothing to be gained by trying to "optimize" this. Even if you come up with something faster, it will be at a significant complexity cost.

Unless you do have positive evidence that this code is affecting your performance, you should use the simplest approach that solves your problem.

Comment: That said, the approach you are displaying, is conceptually a well-known pattern in use for many years for JIT (Just-In-Time) compilation, including .NET's "IL" itself: When a function call is found, it is made to "point" to a compiler call for the source of the function. The first time it's called, what runs is the compiler, which compiles the fragment into machine code and replaces the reference to point to the newly compiled code. Finally, the new code is called and the compiled gets out of the way. JIT is a furiously performance-critical scenario that justifies this kind of complexity.

Comment: @Mark Gravell: > while simple, the null-check approach isn't actually thread-safe... < -- Correct. If the singleton will be called from multiple threads, you should use the Double-checked locking pattern, which is actually guaranteed to work in .NET

Comment: I wasn't actually aiming for a performance gain - this was purely done on a whim, since I feel it adds a bit of elegance. What puzzles me, as I said, is why I haven't seen it before. Surely I can't be the first to have thought of it?

Answer (score 1):

I have just started to program in c# (coming from C++ its a breath of fresh air) and this is what I use to implement singleton patterns.

```
public sealed class MyClass
{    
    #region make singleton

    static readonly Lazy<MyClass> _singleton =
        new Lazy<MyClass>(() => new MyClass());

    public static MyClass Singleton
    {
        get { return _singleton.Value; }
    }

    private MyClass() { Initialize() };

    #endregion

    Initialize() { /*TODO*/ };
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The best method I have found of creating a singleton is this:

```
public class Singleton
{
    static public Singleton Instance { get; } = new Singleton();
    private Singleton() { ... }
}
```

It is very concise, and more importantly, is also **thread safe**, which can be very troublesome to detect and fix as an application matures.

---

Update: To show it is lazy...

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace SingletonTest
{
    class MySingleton
    {
        static public MySingleton Instance { get; } = new MySingleton();

        private MySingleton() { Console.WriteLine("Created MySingleton"); }

        public void DoSomething() { Console.WriteLine("DoSomething"); }
    }

    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Starting Main");

            MySingleton.Instance.DoSomething();
        }
    }
}
```

Output:

```
Starting Main
Created MySingleton
DoSomething
```

Comment: This isn't lazy, though.

Comment: This *is* lazy.

Comment: My mistake - forgot when static initializers ran.

Answer (score 0):

I always use this regular (non-lazy) one (you could nest it like the other examples): (requires `using System.Reflection;`)

```
public class SingletonBase<T> where T : class
{
    static SingletonBase()
    {
    }

    public static readonly T Instance = 
        typeof(T).InvokeMember(typeof(T).Name, 
                                BindingFlags.CreateInstance | 
                                BindingFlags.Instance |
                                BindingFlags.Public |
                                BindingFlags.NonPublic, 
                                null, null, null) as T;
}
```

Comment: I would add the new() constraint to type parameter T. Otherwise this will result in runtime errors.

Comment: I don't allow my singletons to have a public constructor.

Comment: Can you post this on http://stackoverflow.com/questions/100081/whats-a-good-threadsafe-singleton-generic-template-pattern-in-c its the closest to a correct answer I have seen.