# C# ASP.NET Core 6 Web API, Thread Safe, singleton implementation to reuse access tokens

Tags: c#, thread-safety, asp.net-core-webapi, singleton, .net-6.0

My ASP.NET Core 6 Web API A is calling another API B which returns an access token, I want to use the same token (until it expires) to subsequently call multiple operations on B. I created a token class, this will hold the actual value and expiration time of the token

```
public sealed class Token
{
    private static readonly Lazy<Token> lazy =
   new Lazy<Token>(() => new Token());

    public static Token Instance { get { return lazy.Value; } }
   
    public Token()
    {
    } 
 
    public string TokenValue { get; set; }
    public DateTime ExpiresOn { get; set; }

    public bool HasTokenExpired()
    { 
      if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(TokenValue))
      {
        return true;
      }

      if (DateTime.UtcNow >= ExpiresOn.AddSeconds(-20))
      {
        return true;
       }
        return false;           
    }
}
```

Then I have another class that has two operations:

```
Public class TokenResource : ITokenResource
{
    private static Token Token
    {
      get
      {
         return Token.Instance;
      }
     }

    public async Task<string> GetTokenAsync()
    {
        if (Token.HasTokenExpired())
        {
            await RefreshTokenAsync();
        }            
        return Token.TokenValue;                
    }  

    public async Task RefreshTokenAsync()
    {
         // does a http post and gets the token
         var tokenString = JObject.Parse(tokenResponseAsString)["access_token"].Value<string>();            
         Token.TokenValue = tokenString;
         Token.ExpiresOn = SetTokenExpirationDate(tokenString);            
    }
}
```

In startup I am setting the `TokenResource` class as a singleton:

```
 builder.Services.AddSingleton<ITokenResource, TokenResource>();
```

All this seems to work well but I am wondering if this is a correct way to implementing a thread safe singleton, or is this an overkill and we do not need to lock the objects since its already a singleton.

*** - Update - Removed `ReaderWriterLockSlim` and added `Lazy<T>`

Comment: Adding `ITokenResource` as  a `Singleton`  service  ensures the service is constructed once in your application and shared across all your http requests, this does not mean it will prevent multiple threads simultaneously calling `RefreshTokenAsync()` or `HasTokenExpired()`.

Comment: ^ which is why I would suggest using a `Lazy<T>` with a factory method. Then you can get rid of all that locking.

Comment: Out of curiosity, I took it upon me to create a little Fiddle about what I mean by above comment: https://dotnetfiddle.net/IFqWOj If you like it, I can elaborate into an answer.

Comment: Thanks @fildro - I am not very familiar with the `Interlocked.CompareExchange`, but updated my code to reflect a `Lazy<T>` implementation, I did refer to another post which they Q the use of [interlocked](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9316399/2076120)