# How to use 1 List in different forms?

Tags: c#, winforms

I have 9 Forms, in every form i can fill List and i must write content of List to textBox.
I tried to make `public static List<Basket> sas = new List<Basket>();` in Basket.cs , but It doesn't help.

That how i try to output

```
public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        foreach(Basket e in sas)
        {
            basketBox.Text += e.Name + Environment.NewLine;
        }
    }
```

I tried to do like here [How to make a list of classes publicly accessible?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15375265/how-to-make-a-list-of-classes-publicly-accessible) , but it doesn't work.
So, I just want to know how to use 1 List in different forms.

Comment: Maybe [this Q&A](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38768737/3959259) helps you

Comment: `sas` is a static member of the `Basket` class, so in order to access it from outside that class you would need to call it like so: `Basket.sas`, in your `foreach` you're currently trying to access a member of `Form1` called `sas`, which as far as we can tell from the information you have provided does not exist.

Comment: TheHitchenator, God bless you and your family!!! It worked!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just needed to add Basket before sas in foreach.

```
public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        foreach(Basket e in Basket.sas)
        {
            basketBox.Text += e.Name + Environment.NewLine;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You could have your list in a central place.
Creat your own class of Form that takes in the list as a constructor.

Then whenever using one of those forms, pass in the list from the central place in it's constructor.

```
public CustomForm(List<Basket> theList)
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        foreach(Basket e in theList)
        {
            basketBox.Text += e.Name + Environment.NewLine;
        }
    }
```

Usage

```
var frm = new CustomForm(myGlobals.theList);
```

Comment: "that takes in the list as a constructor." how to do this?

Comment: Class name and usage don't match

Answer (score -2):

How about if you create a Session Variable in your first form?

You can do first:

`Session["sas"]=List<Basket>;`

And then in every form:

`foreach(Basket e in (List<Carrito>)Session["sas"])
{
 basketBox.Text += e.Name + Environment.NewLine;
}`

If you dont use anymore:

`Session.Remove("sas");`