# C# - Singleton Pattern Not Working

Tags: singleton, instance, shared

Here is the code I am using:

```
private static WeightRecordsDataSource sharedDataSource;

public static WeightRecordsDataSource SharedDataSource
        {
            get
            {
                if (sharedDataSource == null)
                    sharedDataSource = new WeightRecordsDataSource();

                return sharedDataSource;

            }

        }
```

However, every time SharedDataSource is called, the sharedDataSource is found to be null! and hence a new `WeightRecordsDataSource` is called. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Make it thread safe, see this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/100081/whats-a-good-threadsafe-singleton-generic-template-pattern-in-c-sharp

Comment: How are you calling this?  What are you calling it from?  The singleton exists within a Process.  For example in SSIS, if I have a singleton in a C# script, it appears the next time its called within the same SSIS Run the singleton no longer exists.  Suggesting that the C# Script in a Task, within the same Run is run out of process with Variables passed into it.